# How to call another component from onClick function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am learning Reactjs. I have implemented one sample react app  with rails. I have search a lots to find the solution but I didn't find any. I wanted to call another component from `onClick` function. But nothing happen. Is that possible what I try to achieve? If yes, then please point me where I do mistake and If not, then which way I can implement. Here is my code:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id={"comment_"+ this.props.id }>
        <h4>{ this.props.author } said:</h4>
        <p>{ this.props.desc }</p>
        <a href='' onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</a> | #this is for delete which works great
        <a href='' onClick={this.handleEdit}>Edit</a> 
         # If I put here then it works fine <UpdateComments comments={ this.props} /> but I don't want it here
      </div>
    )
  },
  handleDelete: function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/comments/'+ this.props.id,
      type: "DELETE",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
       this.setState({ comments: data });
      }.bind(this)
    });

  },
  handleEdit: function(event) {
    var Temp = React.createClass({
      render: function(event){
        return(<div>
          <UpdateComments comments={ this.props} /> #here I want to call UpdateComments component
          </div>
        )
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Update:**
If I try below trick then it call the component but reload the page and again disappear called component :(

```
 handleEdit: function() {

    React.render(<UpdateComments comments={ this.props} /> , document.getElementById('comment_'+ this.props.id));
 }
```

any other detail if you required then feel free to ask. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you working with flux or reflux? Currently I'm working with reflux, and I use the store to achieve that.

Comment: @melaspelas : No I am not using flux. simple reactjs

Comment: are you tried https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html??

Comment: @melaspelas : I had check this but couldn't understand how to do with my requirement

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melaspela80/b7b2qona/) could point you in right way

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}
            <First1/>
            <First2/>
        </div>;
    }
});

var First1 = React.createClass({
    myClick: function(){
        alert('Show 1');
        changeFirst();
    },
    render: function() {
        return <a onClick={this.myClick}> Saludo</a>;
    }
});

var First2 = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {myState: ''};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        var me = this;
        window.changeFirst = function() {
            me.setState({'myState': 'Hey!!!'})
            
        }
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        window.changeFirst = null;
    },
    render: function() {
        return <span> Saludo {this.state.myState}</span>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Basically I use those links:

[communicate between components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

[dom event listeners](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html)

It hopes this helps.

Also, you could use the container component and use it like a bridge between both components.